# Select distinct values from a list

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of records and I want to extract a distinct list (RecordList) of values from one column (Due_Date) to populate a ComboBox. I have reviewed all the posted answers here but have not really found what I need. My code is below. This might be something simple, but I have tried a vast number of things to no avail.

```vb
Using context = New iTracContext

    Dim RecordList As New List(Of TrainingRecord)

    If loadAll Then
        RecordList = context.TrainingRecords.Include("TrainingReference").Where(Function(e) e.EmployeeID = EmployeeID).ToList
    Else
        RecordList = context.TrainingRecords.Include("TrainingReference").Where(Function(e) e.EmployeeID = EmployeeID And e.due_date.Year = TrainingManagerForm.YR).ToList
    End If
```

Comment: TrainingRecord has what properties? How do you determine destinctness? From a subset or all of those properties?

Comment: Distinctness is determined by one field only, "Due_Date".

Comment: There are instructions in the documentation for the [Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__). You just need to make the `Equal1` and `GetHashCode1` functions depend on only the field `Due_Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an [EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) based on the date

```vb
Public Class TrainingRecordEqualityComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TrainingRecord)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(x As TrainingRecord, y As TrainingRecord) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TrainingRecord).Equals
        Return x.Due_Date.Equals(y.Due_Date)
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As TrainingRecord) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TrainingRecord).GetHashCode
        Return obj.Due_Date.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

and call [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) on the List

```vb
RecordList = RecordList.Distinct(New TrainingRecordEqualityComparer).ToList()
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I will deep dive into EqualityComparer as this will need to be done quite often.

Comment: For simple types, such as Integer, String, you can simply call `Distinct` and {1, 2, 2, 3} returns {1, 2, 3} for example. For classes with properties, such as in your case, you need to create an EqualityComparer.

Comment: @wakgtech if you are doing this a lot, you can also look into [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) which won't require you to create a new class for each way to determine distinctness. With GroupBy you can pass predicates to select keys and compare them, but you would also need to Select individual elements from the groups afterwards, but it can certainly cut down on the sheer number of classes you would need to create.